# Call a macro under Workbook_BeforeClose only if a specific Workbook is open

Tags: excel, vba

I have already place this code into my PERSONAL.xlsb:

```
Sub CheckInMsg()
    MsgBox "Reminder! Save and Check In this workbook when you are done.", vbInformation, "Closing Reminder"
End Sub
```

From ThisWorkbook, it is Called from:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu
    Call DeleteMasterMenu
    Call CheckInMsg
End Sub
```

But I want this code to run only if a Specific workbook is open (MasterFile.xlsm). I am not sure how to achieve this. Is this something that needs to be added into the Workbook_BeforeClose sub? Or in the CheckInMsg sub?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event you could cycle through all of the open workbooks, and if you find the name you are looking for, you do the three calls. Something like:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name = "MasterFile.xlsm" Then
        Call DeleteFromCellMenu
        Call DeleteMasterMenu
        Call CheckInMsg
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. However, can I run the two Calls (Call DeleteFromCellMenu and Call DeleteMasterMenu) before the DIM statement? And I am assuming you would place this code into the Private Sub I have in ThisWorkbook?

Comment: Yep. Whatever you want to execute ONLY when that workbook is open, goes inside the For/If block. If you always want something to execute regardless of the workbook being open, then stick it outside of the For/If block. Also, yes, this would go inside your `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as boolean)` subroutine.

Comment: I guess, too, you could stick the For/If block inside your other sub and put your `msgbox()` call inside of it. It will work where ever you need it. It's pretty flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Very informative and the answer addressed the all aspects of the question. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function:

```
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

And then use it in your code:

```
If IsFileOpen("c:\Book2.xls") Then

    'do stuff

End If
```

If you don't want to use function, you can implement this code into your sub.